# Steps of multiple object tracking

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, tracking

I am searching on people tracking and reading about detection based tracking. the steps as I understood is:

1- detection

2- position or any feature from bbox of detected person

3- matching with next frame detection

4- using tracker to connect tracklet to detected person

5- repeat steps again

the question are these steps right?  and how to benefit from dataset that provide detection information (can you please show which dataset provides detection information).

Also, is the tracker responsibility for connecting two matched bbox? or?

Regards

Comment: Your steps are generally correct, but there are many different approaches for how to implement each step, especially in regards to your second question, how to use supervised training data.  
Human or pedestrian detection and tracking is an active area of research and probably beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer. I would suggest reading some research papers; they will provide details of the method used and the datasets.

Comment: Dear Cecilia, Thanks for your answer .. Actually I have read a lot of paper and I am just confused that some papers just used a tracker for tracking and others used both Association algorithm and tracker. What the difference between them.

Comment: Check out Mathworks site: [article](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/multiple-object-tracking.html) and [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html), even if you don't have the toolbox.